# Does psql \dt cache schema?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I have a session running in `psql` it does not show newly created tables (from another connection but for the current owner role).

If I re-login they show up. Do I need to refresh a psql cache somehow or is this related to transaction/sessions or cached permissions?

Comment: `psql` doesn't use a cache. If you do `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`  it will display the queries corresponding to backslash commands such as `\dt` as they are issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem, the other session did not only create those tables but also modified the Schema search path (which was not active in the existing session of course)